# Next action is not assignable to type string

Tags: typescript, next.js, next.js14

I'm working on a project using Next.js 14 and I've encountered an issue with server actions.

I have a submit function:

```
async function submit(formData: FormData) {
  // function implementation
}
```

I'm using it in a form element like this:

```
<form action={submit}>
  {/* form elements */}
</form>
```

However, when I run the `build` command, I encounter the following type error:

> Type error: Type '(formData: FormData) => Promise' is not
> assignable to type 'string'.

What causes this error and how do I solve it?

Comment: Kind of looks ok but would be better if you could show the entire thing put together ([mcve]) instead of little snippets

Comment: I think that next.js expects to use server action when using action of form instead of client function

Comment: No additional code is required. The issue arises from a TypeScript error due to HTML expecting a string, whereas Next.js utilizes a function. To bypass the linting process, I'm using the // @ts-nocheck directive.

Comment: I am perplexed as to why this question was closed. There is a clear error provided in the post, and the problem is perfectly well explained.

Comment: @PabloCegarra, for me, this was an issue with type definitions. In my package.json I had `"@types/react": "^18.2.0"` and `"@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0"` in dependencies, but in dev-dependencies I had     `"@types/react": "18.0.28"` and `"@types/react-dom": "18.0.11"`. Updating the dev-deps fixed it.

Comment: is `submit` a server actilon or a regular function

Comment: Seems like some examples use `<button formAction=...` and the same error is there with that.