# Typescript does not accept additional prop from server action function on useFormState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, server-action

I'm having trouble trying to integrate the Next.js server actions with useFormState (for displaying input errors on client side) and Typescript.

Following their official documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/improving-accessibility), they suggest to add a new prop to the server action function, as for example:

```
export async function createInvoice(prevState: State, formData: FormData)
```

In their example, they add the server action function as a first parameter to the useFormState, like this:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(createInvoice, initialState);
```

In my case that is:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(action, initialState);
```

Where `action` is the server action function received from my form page.

Typescript is complaining about the action type, how to fix it?

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(action: (state: { message: null; errors: {}; }) => Promise<{ message: null; errors: {}; }>, initialState: { message: null; errors: {}; }, permalink?: string | undefined): [state: { message: null; errors: {}; }, dispatch: () => void]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prevState: State, formData: FormData) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { message: null; errors: {}; }) => Promise<{ message: null; errors: {}; }>'.
      Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(action: (state: { message: null; errors: {}; }, payload: FormData) => Promise<{ message: null; errors: {}; }>, initialState: { message: null; errors: {}; }, permalink?: string | undefined): [state: ...]', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(prevState: State, formData: FormData) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(state: { message: null; errors: {}; }, payload: FormData) => Promise<{ message: null; errors: {}; }>'.
      Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise<{ message: null; errors: {}; }>'.ts(2769)
(parameter) action: (prevState: State, formData: FormData) => void
```

Follow my Form component code:

```
import { useFormState } from "react-dom";
import { State } from "@/types/formState";

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  action: string | ((prevState: State, formData: FormData) => void) | undefined;
};

const Form = ({ children, action }: Props) => {
  const initialState = { message: null, errors: {} };

  const [state, dispatch] = useFormState(action, initialState);

  return (
    <form
      action={dispatch}
      className="w-full flex justify-center"
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <div className={`w-full`}>
        {children}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

The page where I call the Form component above:

```
import { createUserAccount } from "@/actions/createUserAccount";
import Form, { Button, InputText } from "@/components/Form";

type Props = {};

const SignUpPage = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Form action={createUserAccount}>
      <div className="items-center mb-4 flex relative">
        <InputText
          name="firstname"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your first name"
          required
        />
      </div>

      <div className="items-center mb-4 flex relative">
        <InputText
          name="lastname"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter your last name"
          required
        />
      </div>

      <div className="items-center mb-4 flex relative">
        <Button title="Join Now" type="submit" />
      </div>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default SignUpPage;
```

And my server action function (`createUserAccount`):

```
"use server";

import { State } from "@/types/formState";
import userAccountSchema from "@/validation/schemas/createUserAccount";

export async function createUserAccount(prevState: State, formData: FormData) {
  const parsedData = userAccountSchema.safeParse({
    firstname: formData.get("firstname"),
    lastname: formData.get("lastname"),
  });

  // Check if the parsing was not successful
  if (!parsedData.success) {
    return {
      errors: parsedData.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
    };
  }

  // Process validated data
  // ...
  return { success: true };
}
```

The code returns the input errors with no problems when tested. The issue apparently is only about the Typescript.

Thank you!

**Edit #1**

Follow my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "project_name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "14.0.4",
    "react": "^18.2.46",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "sass": "^1.69.7",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.10.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.46",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.4.33",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77527700/next-action-is-not-assignable-to-type-string#comment136716298_77527700) suggests updating dependencies should help

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/59475

Comment: Hey @Phil ... I've updated the dependencies but the issue still, also checked the other link you posted but that didn't give me a better idea on how to fix it...

Comment: I have edited my post with my package.json

Comment: It seems that it does not like the way you defined the type of `action` in `Props`. My guess is that you need to specify that the `action` returns a `Promise`

Comment: Are you missing "use client" in the top as per the documentation ?

Comment: That was it @zoran404 ! Thanks! I will add an answer to update with the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct signature for your `action` prop would be:

```
type Props = {
  action: (prevState: State, formData: FormData) => State | Promise<State>;
  /* ... */
};
```

It has to be a function and that function has to return a new State or a promise of a new State.

It can not be a `string`.
You may have thought that it is a string, because you are passing the callback to `<form action="...">`.
In vanilla React you would have to use a string for the form action, but in NextJS you can pass functions.

And the action is a required parameter, so it can not be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

in server action when you are using `useFormState`, type of first argument of the action and the type of return value have to be same:

```
 action: (prevState: State, formData: FormData) => void;
```

`prevState` has type of State so the return value also should be the same

```
action: (prevState: State, formData: FormData) => Promise<State>;
```

that is because how type of `useFormState` type is defined:

```
function useFormState<State>(action: (state: Awaited<State>) => State | Promise<State>, initialState: Awaited<State>, permalink?: string): [state: Awaited<State>, dispatch: () => void]
```